# Replacement for deprecated .WeekdayCalendarUnit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nscalendar

I updated Xcode a couple weeks ago and started getting a warning on this line:

```
let weekdayComponent = currentCalendar?.components(.WeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
```

> 'WeekdayCalendarUnit' was deprecated in iOS version 8.0: Use
>   NSCalendarUnitWeekday instead

But when I replace `.WeekdayCalendarUnit` with `.NSCalendarUnitWeekday`, I get a "could not find member .NSCalendarUnitWeekday" error. I tried a few other varieties but no luck.

What should we be using instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little tricky.  Check the format.  Here you go:

```
let weekdayComponent = currentCalendar?.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: date)
```

Or:

```
let weekdayComponent = currentCalendar?.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: date)
```

I was able to find the right format in the [NSCalendar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSCalendarUnit)

Comment: .CalendarUnitWeekday worked! And thanks for the reference link.